# Termial not accepting options

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, ruby

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, and for some reason the terminal command will not accept options.
(I believe these are called option, please correct me if I am wrong).

For example, when installing a new version of ruby using rvm, I get an error when I do:

```
--no-rdoc --no-ri
```

Apologies for not having the exact error. I installed the (very) long way and cannot replicate the exact error. However, it was something along the lines of it not recognizing rdoc (or ri when I did it in reverse.)

Same issue happening when I'm in Rails.  When using a generator, it *ignores* the options.  For example:

```
rails generate model User --pretend  #--pretend is *ignored*
```

It seems to accept the args, i.e. `User` (above), but it ignores the `--pretend` option.

For reference, when I have used this option in the past, it has worked.  The correct behavior is to list all of the created files, directories, etc. (in the terminal window), while not actually creating the files (so that you know what you are about to get).  By ignoring the option, it is as if I am generating a User model, and does (incorrectly) run the command, thus creating the files.

Comment: Is this only for `ruby` related commands or for all commands?

Comment: It appears so.  Honestly, I only know a few other commands that have options, but I tried them and they appear to work, so you might be onto something there.  Any additional thought would be much appreciated.  Thanks!